# How to use Intent to launch the satellite application on android?

Tags: android

Hai Frnds,
          i want to know to launch a satellite application using Intent, i knew how to launch the map application using Intent, but i want to display satellite view rather than map view, my code is

```
   uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + VALUE_baraddress1[0] + ", "
            + VALUE_baraddress2[0] + ", "
            + VALUE_baraddress3[0]);
            Log.v(TAG, VALUE_baraddress1[0] + ", "
            + VALUE_baraddress2[0] + ", "
            + VALUE_baraddress3[0]);
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Code you posted is wake up the `streetview` fo a particular Geopoint. if you want to drop a pin on the google maps then you have to change the uri value. these all are explained well in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) itself.